# How to make linregress from scipy skip through empty cells

Tags: python, scipy, spotfire

I am new to Python and am currently trying to learn how to utilize it with Spotfire.

Currently, I have a table - let's say it has X, Y, and Z data - where some rows are missing due to errors.

I added six extra columns with different Y filters, where each column attempts to retrieve Y data for a different Z condition.

This is what I've tried.

```
from scipy import stats

DP1

Slope1= stats.linregress(DP1['x'],DP1['y1'].slope
```

However, since there may be times when y1 equals are not available if all other Y columns are included in the table, filtering the new table for Y1 to exclude empty values would yield a number. But I am looking for a more efficient method to do this for all other Y values.

Answer (score 0):

With scipy.stats.linregress(..) you can also send in a data frame provided it has two columns.

So to skip the empty values of y1 (or any other y column) and automatically send the corresponding values of x you could try:

```
stats.linregress(DP1[['x','y1']].dropna()).slope
stats.linregress(DP1[['x','y2']].dropna()).slope
etc.
```

In each case you are only considering the rows in which both columns are non null.